# KendoUI Treeview expand nodes based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a kenodui treeview that I am trying to expand the top level nodes if they have the following values: "Active" or "Closed", the remaining nodes can remain closed. I am using the following code to create my treeview:

```
if (CI.Popup.treeview == null) {
        CI.Popup.treeview = $("#RelatedPropertyListing").kendoTreeView({
            template: "#= item.Name #",
            dataImageUrlField: "image",
            dataSource: CI.Popup.treeDS,
            dataTextField: ["Name", "Name"],
            encoded: true
        }).data("kendoTreeView");
    }
```

My datasource is defined as a json `kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource`. I have tried generating the treeview using html instead of a datasource but it was unbareably slow so I have to use this method.

Any ideas how I can expand only those nodes that have a value of "Active" or "Closed"???

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can slightly change your returned data, you can set `expanded` to `true` for each node that you want expanded and KendoUI will automatically take care of it.

Example:

```
var data = [
    {
        text    : "node 1",
        expanded: true,
        items   : [
            { text: "node 1.1" },
            {
                text    : "node 1.2",
                expanded: false,
                items   : [
                    { text: "node 1.2.1" },
                    { text: "node 1.2.2" },
                    { text: "node 1.2.3" }
                ]
            },
            { text: "node 1.3" }
        ]
    }
];

var treeview = $("#treeview-left").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource  : data,
    loadOnDemand: true
}).data("kendoTreeView");
```

JSFiddle in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/RbFyN/)